# Java serialization readResolve method and kryo

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

I'm trying to transfer a class containing a transient field (a Cache which makes no sense to serialize). In the past that field was recreated using the readResolve method offered by the standard java serialization framework.

```java
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

  private transient LoadingCache<Key, Value> someCache;

//this works when using default java tools. I need an equivalent method in kryo framework
  Object readResolve() {
    someCache = createNewCache();
    return this;
  }
}
```

Kryo does not to execute that method, **is there a different way to tell kryo what needs to be done with a deserialized object to reinit state?**

A custom serializer is not an option, there are already many different serializers in the project which would all need adjusting.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution but I'm still open for something better:
I created an annotation which is added on the target method of a deserialized object.
Then I added a custom com.esotericsoftware.kryo.ClassResolver which scans new registrations for that annotation.

If its found the serializer for that registration is wrapped in a delegating serializer which executes the annotated method once the object is recreated.